# How to replace failed disk on Linux Raid (mdadm)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm

I get an input/output error when I list drives with: `fdisk -l`

```
Failed to read extended partition table (offset=3886721022): Input/output error
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7ac0eeb9

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048 3886718975 3886716928  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       3886721022 3907028991   20307970  9.7G  5 Extended

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7ac0eeb9

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048 3886718975 3886716928  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       3886721022 3907028991   20307970  9.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       3886721024 3907028991   20307968  9.7G fd Linux raid autodetect

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/md1: 9.7 GiB, 10389291008 bytes, 20291584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md0: 1.8 TiB, 1989864849408 bytes, 3886454784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Then, `/proc/mdstat`:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[2]
      1943227392 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 15/15 pages [60KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sdb5[2]
      10145792 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      
unused devices: <none>
```

Then: `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Mar 20 06:41:14 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1943227392 (1853.21 GiB 1989.86 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1943227392 (1853.21 GiB 1989.86 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Thu Nov 23 16:21:07 2023
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : impacs:0
           UUID : 619c5551:3e475969:80882df7:7da3f864
         Events : 18817061

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       2       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Then: `mdadm --detail /dev/md1`:

```
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Mar 20 06:41:40 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 10145792 (9.68 GiB 10.39 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 10145792 (9.68 GiB 10.39 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Nov 23 14:19:34 2023
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : impacs:1
           UUID : 1b9a0dc4:cc30cd7e:274fefd9:55266436
         Events : 70615

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       2       8       21        1      active sync   /dev/sdb5
```

I don't see `/dev/sda` there, how can I know if it is used in the RAID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only clue I see is this:

```
/dev/sda1             2048 3886718975 3886716928  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect
```

It appears that your `/dev/sda` partition table, and probably `/dev/sda1`, is so messed up that RAID doesn't try to keep either `sda1` or the no longer available `sda5` in the disk array. So I'd say that it's about 99% certain that `/dev/sda` is half of your RAID arrays, and that it is dead and needs to be replaced.